# Data not displaying when doing an ajax request in React

Tags: reactjs, components, containers

So I'm trying to mock an ajax call using a React's Container(purely to fetch the data and pass it along to its children), but I'm not getting anything.

Instead get the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. Which basically tells me that the `users` is either empty or not yet defined, right?

Right now I'm following the following structure `UserListContainer` (fetches the data) => `UserList Component` (displays the data as a prop).

**UserList Container**

```
// Container responsible only to fetch User data
import React from 'react';
import UserList from '../../ui/components/users/userList.jsx';


export default class UserListContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            users: []
        }
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        $.ajax({
            // url: "../../users/users.json",
            url: "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dantesolis/267a298f3d6ac524bc2a7d80960a16b5/raw/7929bb23f1757b85adcead4eed3023cd3c7453df/users.json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(users) {
                this.setState({users: users});
            }.bind(this)
        });
    }

    render() {

        // const usr = this.props.user;
        // let usrs = users_mockup ? users_mockup : this.props.users;

        return (
            <UserList users={this.state.users} />
        );
    }
}
```

**UserList Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import User from '../users/user.jsx';
// import { Link } from 'react';
    

export default class UserList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    renderUser({name, _id}) {
        return <li>{_id}-{name}</li>
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="main">
                <ul>{this.props.users.map(renderUser)}</ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because `users` is `undefined` in the `success` callback. This can happen because the URL is not working correctly. After taking a look [at it](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dantesolis/267a298f3d6ac524bc2a7d80960a16b5/raw/7929bb23f1757b85adcead4eed3023cd3c7453df/users.json), it seems it returns javascript and not json. You should try removing the comment in the first line to make it json compliant.

Comment: Gonzales, still having the same problem. I would love to see what's inside that user variable but cannot get a `console.log` to work

Comment: I substituted the url with the same JSON [without the comment in the first line](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dgonz64/c296dd465b91dd09ff65e1b5aeec66f8/raw/895edcadc3796c42932b2ecb266d7fc845f02214/test-another-json.json) and it works (I get the objects). You can try by adding `error` callback to `$.json` to see if there's a problem in your environment or setup. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: are you fetching the data via `curl` or how? I'm getting it via `curl`, but not o my react app. Thanks for the link. Let me take a look.

Comment: I just made a React application with your code. To be sincere I substituted `UserList` with `p`.